# Prevent Oracle Database Error by Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle11g, wildfly

I have some trouble but not necessary.

Because my `JSP/Servlet` is work fine but **sometime** I have these **connection Error** Like this

> **Connection Error Records:**
>
> ```
> ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again 
>
> ORA-01012: not logged on
>
> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-02399: exceed maximum connect time, you are being logged off
> ```

**.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="my.OracleConnectionPool" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% 
Connection connect = null;
Statement s = null;
try {        
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   connect =  OracleConnectionPool.getConnection();
   s = connect.createStatement();
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
   ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);
   //Do something
} catch (Exception e) {
   out.println(e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   try {
      s.close();
      connect.close();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
      out.println(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
%>
```

**my.OracleConnectionPool** this will get connection from `wildfly`

```java
package my;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
public class OracleConnectionPool {
  public OracleConnectionPool() {
  }
  public static Connection getConnection()
          throws SQLException {
    try {
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      DataSource ods = null;
      ods = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/MYCON");
      if (ods == null) {
        throw new SQLException("OracleDataSource is null.");
      }
      return ods.getConnection();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

For the Standalone.xml

```
<datasource enabled="true" pool-name="MYCON" jndi-name="java:/MYCON" use-ccm="false" jta="true">
   <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:ODS</connection-url>
   <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
   <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
   <security>
      <user-name>myuser</user-name>
      <password>********</password>
   </security>
   <validation>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
      <background-validation>true</background-validation>
      <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
      <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
   </validation>
</datasource>
```

How can I prevent or skip these error?
Should I try the refresh servlet/connect test first?

**Update:** Because I can't change Oracle's PDA

Comment: is `my.OracleConnectionPool` a class you wrote? I think that it should be testing the connections before returning them to the client, and discarding them if necessary.

Comment: Assuming `OracleConnectionPool` is a custom connection pooling implementation in `OracleConnectionPool.getConnection()` you can check the connection is valid by firing `select 1 form dual` if the connection is closed create a new connection and return it.

Comment: @tgdavies Yes is my class will return as `DataSource` it connect to database and work fine

Comment: I have work on `wildfly`

Comment: The problem is in your connection pool, not in your servlet. The connection pool is keeping connections open for a long time (as it should) so it needs to check that they have not timed out periodically.

Comment: not work with `connect.close();` in finally?

Comment: Please show your connection pool configuration for `"java:/MYCON"`. You can find this in the WildFly standalone.xml configuration file.

Comment: I have added some `standalone.xml` for `"java:/MYCON"` @SteveC

Comment: Where is it exactly that you see these `Connection Error Records`?

Comment: `out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: on statement call

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with your database profiles.  Even if you can workaround the problem with connection pool settings, you should still try to fix this on the database side.  If you see this problem once, chances are it's impacting other users and other tools that may not have a workaround.

First, find out which profile applies to your user:

```
select username, profile
from dba_users
order by username;
```

The most common way for these problems to occurs is for users to be in the wrong profile.  Make sure your application account is not stuck in a user profile.  DBAs typically set up at least two kinds of profiles - one for user accounts, that forces disconnects, and one for application accounts, that never forces disconnects.

If the user is in the right profile, check the profile values.  Your application user should probably have a value of `UNLIMITED` for the resources `CONNECT_TIME` and `IDLE_TIME`.

```
select profile, resource_name, limit
from dba_profiles
where resource_name in ('IDLE_TIME', 'CONNECT_TIME')
order by 1,2;
```

If your application profile is set to a small value, you may need to run a command like this:

```
alter profile your_profile limit connect_time unlimited;
```

Comment: Thank for solution I have seen `java:MYCON`'s user have `60 connect_time`

Comment: **But Unfortunely** I don't have permission to change dba... may i use retry from client side

Comment: You should speak to a database administrator about this issue.  They *should* want to change it and be glad that you brought it up.  (But I know how unhelpful many DBAs can be, so prepare yourself for disappointment.)

Comment: Because reduce database server's load